# Check to see if the function $f$ which satisfies the following relation is one-to-one or not: $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R: f(x+f(y))=f(x)+y$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Check to see if the function $f$ which satisfies the following relation is one-to-one or not:
>   $$\forall x,y\in \Bbb R: f(x+f(y))=f(x)+y$$

Please judge my solution:
I set $y=0$ to get: $f(x+f(0))=f(x)$, now I deduce that this function is one to one if $f(0)=0$, otherwise, for example, $5+f(0)\ne 5$ but  $f(x+f(0))=f(x)$. Am I correct??

Comment: You can use that to prove that it isn't one-to-one unless $f(0)=0$, but not that it *is* one-to-one if $f(0)=0$.

Comment: For finish the case when $f(0)=0$ (to prove that really is one to one): Putting $x=0$ then $f^2(y)=y$ for all $y$. Is clear that is $f$ surjective because for all $y$ exists $x=f(y)$ such that $f(x)=y$. Also, $f$ is injective, because if for $x,x'$ then $f(x)=f(x')=y$, we have $x=f^2(x)=f(y)=f^2(x')=x'$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo I don't think that's a finish yet. Perhaps it's possible to (dis)prove that $f(0)=0$, so we can conclusively say whether the function is one-to-one or not.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes. He proved that $\text{one to one}\to f(0)=0$. I proved that $f(0)=0\to \text{one to one}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ satisfies $f(x+f(y))=f(x)+y$, $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$, then I'll prove that $f$ is injective.

Let $P(x,y)$ be the statement $f(x+f(y))=f(x)+y$.

Let $f(0)=c$.

$P(-c,0)\implies c=f(-c)$

$P(-c,-c)\implies c=0$

$P(0,y)\implies f(f(y))=y$, $\forall y\in\mathbb R$

If $f(a)=f(b)$, then $f(f(a))=f(f(b))$, so $a=b$. So $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect; rather, the conclusion is the converse of what you said.  If $f(0)\neq 0$, then you are correct that $f$ will not be one-to-one.  However, if $f(0)=0$, then you cannot conclude that $f$ is one-to-one (all you know is that one possible approach to showing it is not one-to-one fails).

Comment: So would you please complete the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: next assume $f(0)=0$, and see what you get by taking $x=0$.